# How to make haddock documentation link to documentation of other packages?

Tags: windows, haskell, documentation, cabal, haddock

Minimal example: I have a Cabal project with the following structure:

```
Test
  Test.cabal
  Test.hs
```

The code file:

```
{-
Description: Description.

* Description
-}
module Test (test) where
  -- | Test.
  test :: Int
  test = 0
```

The cabal file:

```
cabal-version: 3.8
author: Liisi Kerik
category: Test
description:
  Description.
name: Test
synopsis: Synopsis.
version: 0.0.0
library
  build-depends: base
  exposed-modules: Test
  ghc-options: -Wall
```

`cabal haddock` works but I get a warning:

```
Warning: The documentation for the following packages are not installed. No
links will be generated to these packages: base-4.18.0.0, ghc-bignum-1.3,
ghc-prim-0.10.0
 100% (  2 /  2) in 'Test'
Warning: Test: could not find link destinations for:

        - GHC.Types.Int
```

and the resulting html documentation contains no link to the documentation of `Int`.

I'm on Windows 10, GHC 9.6.2, Cabal 3.10.1.0.

I know that similar questions have been asked before but I don't understand the solutions, can't make them work or they're Linux-specific.

Comment: Specifically _what_ solutions have you tried and what prevents them from making them work for you?

Comment: I can't use that one since the solution is Linux-specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095109/haddock-could-not-find-link-destinations-for I also tried to reinstall packages: ```cabal install --reinstall --upgrade-dependencies world``` But that just threw an error. I'm not using sandbox, so sandbox-related answers aren't relevant. ```cabal v2-haddock --haddock-html-location='https://hackage.haskell.org/package/$pkg-$version/docs' --haddock-hyperlink-source --haddock-quickjump``` That one just doesn't help, the documentation is still missing the links.